# Type mismatch when passing component as variable to ngx-bootstrap modal service

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm following the example [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview#service-component) to create an ngx-bootstrap modal from a component.

However, if I create a variable for the component using the ternary operator, I get a weird compiler error if I don't declare my variable separately from assigning it.

In other words, this works:

```
let modal;
modal = someParameter ? FooComponent : BarComponent;
this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(modal);
```

(Note that both `FooComponent` and `BarComponent` extend a common base class.)

But if I try this:

```
let modal = someParameter ? FooComponent : BarComponent;
this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(modal);
```

I get a compile-time error like:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof FooComponent | typeof BarComponent' is not
assignable to parameter of type 'string | TemplateRef<any> |
(new (...args: any[]) => BarComponent)'.

Type 'typeof BarComponent' is not assignable to type 'string | TemplateRef<any> |
(new (...args: any[]) => FooComponent)'.

Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
```

There follows some additional complaining that the two subclasses don't share identical properties.

What seems to be happening is that compiler is randomly picking one class or another as the type signature to test against, rather than honoring the `|` which it seems to recognize in the initial part of the error message. But I don't understand why, or why separating the declaration from the assignment makes the problem go away.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: try using this code `let modal: Type<FooComponent> | Type<BarComponent> = someParameter ? FooComponent : BarComponent;`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use multiple `this.modalService.open()` for each of the components, but seems like a ineffecient way to resolve your problem, so I would suggest you convert the type to one of the components, this will resolve your issue!

Note this type is only used to open the modal, it wont interfere with the typing anywhere else, in the modal component!

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(
  (this.test
    ? ModalContentComponent
    : ModalContentTwoComponent) as typeof ModalContentComponent
);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kfawd2?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,tsconfig.json&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I'm confused why one would do this, since the two components are descendants of a common parent class but have different type signatures and constructors.

Comment: @sumizome it's because you want the code to compile and typescript is blocking you, it seems like a trivial scenario because no code will get affected and you just want the code to compile, so this is the best fix in my opinion, after the open method is run, there is no need for that typing

Comment: @sumizome its an internal problem in the package where the typing does not support multiple types, no code is perfect, so we need few workarounds, but this is a simple scenario, so its just a bug, but there is no major impact due to this bug!